# Scared? dual-boot my MBP, but I lost Mac OSX?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, mac, macosx

It seems I made a blunder, but it's unclear. Originally, I had a standard MBP 2012, and I decided to dual-booting my computer (i.e. Mac OSX and Ubuntu). I download Ubuntu 16.10 (ISO) and, with a external drive, I installed Ubuntu 16.10 with the application UNetBootin. Actually, I'm a bit scared, because I've really installed Ubuntu 16.10, but I have no longer access to Mac OSX. When I restart my Mac, I don't have the choice between Mac OSX and Ubuntu. It come back each time to Ubuntu. Is it somehow the first choice by default? Could anyone be able to give a bit more explanation? Am I right to be scared or not?

Comment: You can try running `sudo update-grub` in a terminal and seeing if macOS shows up in the GRUB boot menu. If not, you probably chose to "Erase disk and install Ubuntu."

Comment: @Zacharee1 Is there a way to retrieve Mac OSX?? I think I lost everything...

Comment: First, stop using Ubuntu. Shut the computer down, unless you don't have another around to use to continue this troubleshooting. Refer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu. It should apply to HFS+ partitions, though I'm not sure.

Comment: I had created a back-up  as asking, but I used the same external hard drive to bootable Ubuntu. So I had the idea of genius of forwarding my back-up on the Document directory on my MBP.

Comment: I don't think it's established that OS X, your data or both were removed or overwritten. It could just be a faulty or misconfigured boot loader. Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? Thanks.